# working in mysql but not in db2. SQL State: 42601] DB2 SQL Error: SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC==;sum(day(p.create_dt);CONCAT

Tags: mysql, db2

Below is my query

```
select YEAR(p.create_dt) as year,
       month(p.create_dt) as month,
       p.system as systemName,
       p.status as status,
       sum(day(p.create_dt) = '01') as count1,
       sum(day(p.create_dt) = '02') as count2
from pnm_history p
group by year(p.create_dt),
        month(p.create_dt)
order by year(p.create_dt),
         month(p.create_dt);
```

getting error near sum()

Comment: The subject of your question should be brief and in the form of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `day()` calls in MySQL with `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT p2.year,
       p2.month,
       p1.system AS systemName,
       p1.status AS status,
       p2.count1,
       p2.count2
FROM pnm_history p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(p.create_dt) AS year,
           MONTH(p.create_dt) AS month,
           SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(p.create_dt) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(p.create_dt) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2
    FROM pnm_history p
    GROUP BY YEAR(p.create_dt),
             MONTH(p.create_dt)
) p2
    ON YEAR(p1.create_dt)  = p2.year AND
       MONTH(p1.create_dt) = p2.month
ORDER BY p2.year,
         p2.month
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, sum() working fine, but if i write more fields like in the above query  "p.system as systemName,p.status as status,etc" the query is failed and  hitting   "errorDB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=STATUS"

Comment: You can't add those fields because they are not aggregates or columns mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Rightfully, you got an error, and even some versions of MySQL would also have given you an error.

Comment: Is there any work around to fix this issue ?? Bcz i need all fields in db2

Comment: becoz as per my requirement i need only those year() and month() to be grouped and rest i no need for grouping since the result will change

Comment: @harika I gave you a query which should suit your needs, even on earlier versions of DB2.

Comment: why not add system and status to the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @WarrenT Because those columns are not aggregates.  It won't work, except maybe on certain versions of MySQL.

Comment: exactly. they are not aggregates. that's why I suggested putting them in the GROUP BY clause, where you would not put aggregates

Comment: This isn't what the OP intended AFAIK.